# Getting Applescript to do some work

Tags: applescript

I have two files.

One has a list of words.  The other has a large list of words that includes all words in the original file.  How can I write a script to search all words in list 1 and get the line on list 2 with that exact word (list 2 has the words plus additional information) and write them to a third file?

I've been searching online but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Sounds like homework, frankly. You're not going to find anything that does that specifically, you're going to have to code it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at sed, awk or grep one of those tools should be the right direction...